# python dict update trouble

Tags: python, dictionary

i'm using Python with MongoDB

why this code is working:

```
for record in connection.collection.find():
    mydict = dict(record)
    mydict.update({"key": "value"})
    mylist.append(mydict)
```

result:

```
{"data": [{"anotherkey": "anothervalue"},{"key": "value"}]}
```

and this code is **not** working

```
for record in connection.collection.find():
    mydict = dict(record).update({"key": "value"})
    mylist.append(mydict)
```

result:

```
{"data": [null, null]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update is an *inplace* operation mutating the original object:

**update([other])**

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. **Return None**.

You can use `**` to get the behaviour you want:

```
mydict = dict(record,**{"key": "value"})
 mylist.append(mydict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `dict.update()` is in-place, it does not return anything. So when you do -

```
mydict = dict(record).update({"key": "value"})
```

`mydict` is actually `None` , as if a function does not return anything in python, it by default returns `None`.

And then when you do - `mylist.append(mydict)` - you are just appending `None` (in the second case) .